# Is reverse of p-value also uniformly distributed?

Tags: p-value, conditional-probability

If p-value, $p(F|H_0)$, is uniformly distributed $U[0,1]$, so is true to say, that $p(F|H_1)$ is also uniformly distributed $U[0,1]$ or even more: is it true $p(F|H_0) = 1-p(F|H_1)$?

I'm not sure if it's called "reverse".

[Update] F stands for "finding", sample statistic. I want to check if $p(H_0|F)$ is close enough to $p(F|H_0)$ (p-value). To do that I used this code:

```
m=1000
p_F_H_0=runif(m,0,1)
p_F_H_1=runif(m,0,1)
p_H_0=rbeta(m, shape1=500, shape2=100)
p_H_0_F=(p_F_H_0*p_H_0)/(p_F_H_0*p_H_0+p_F_H_1*(1-p_H_0)) #Bayes theorem
tab=cbind(p_F_H_0, p_H_0_F)
corrr=cor(tab[,1], tab[,2], method="pearson")
```

And later, I started to have doubts if it's correct.

Comment: No, neither of the things you suggest there are true.

Comment: @Glen_b so how to calculate the distribution of $p(F|H_1)$ ?

Comment: Most likely it will not be possible without the prior. What is your $H_0$ and $H_1$?

Comment: @psarka Not specified directly. I tried to calculate correlation between $p(H_0|F)$ and $p(F|H_0)$, using the Bayes theorem, assuming that $p(H_0)$ has a beta distribution and $p(F|H_0)$ is missing...

Comment: One of us is horribly confused, and I will assume it is me. Unless you want to write your question in detail I'll be unable to say anything clever.

Comment: @psarka It can be me, who is confused:-) I've read that "some people believe,  that the probability of the data if given the null hypothesis correlates with the probability of the null hypothesis if given the data". So I wanted to check this. I have $p(F|H_0)$~$U[0,1]$, and I assume beta distribution to $p(H_0)$ bounded to $[0,1]$ interval. Then I use the Bayes theorem, to calculate $p(H_0|F)$. I assumed that $p(F|H_1)$ is $U[0,1]$. After this one calculation I get one number, that $p(H_0|F)$, but I'm doing this, say, 1000 times. So I can correlate $p(F|H_0)$ with calculated $p(H_0|F)$.

Comment: Given you call $p(F|H_0)$ the p-value, I assume $F$ is the event "a sample statistic at least as extreme as the observed one". If you specify the test, and the exact alternative situation, and any other things required to compute the distribution of the statistic under the particular alternative, as well as the observed value of the statistic, then it should be computable. If you want me to say much more then (i) you have a lot of things you need to specify for it to be answered, and (ii) that sounds like quite a different question to the one you posted (so you would ask another question).